# Quick Sort algorithm not working

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, while-loop, quicksort

I'm working on a quick sort algorithm for a Huffman coding project I'm working on (explains why all the function names start with huff). When walking through it with the debugger, the function seems to freeze when finding the highest term (when trying to find the term from the right side of the vector which "should not" be on that side). There may (probable are) other problems with this code but i'm focussing on this one for now. By the way, most of the time (all of the time) I call cout, it's for debugging purposes.

Edit: A lot of corrections have been made to my code from the comments, but none of them fix my problem. For that reason, I'm updating the code.

```
void huff_sort_partition(vector<Node*>* v, int b, int e){
    int tempt = b+((rand()%(e-b))+1);
    int p_idx = (*v)[tempt]->weight;
    cout << tempt << endl;
    int l = b+0;
    int r = e;
    cout << "P:" << p_idx << "  L-R:" << l << "-" << r << endl;
    while(l < r){
        while((*v)[l]->weight < p_idx){
            l++;
        }
        while((*v)[r]->weight > p_idx){
            r--;
        }
        Node* s = (*v)[b+l];
        (*v)[b+l] = (*v)[b+r];
        (*v)[b+r] = s;
    }

    huff_sort_partition(v, b, l-1);
    huff_sort_partition(v, l+1, e);
}
void Huff::huff_sort(vector<Node*>* v){
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout << "------sort------" << endl;
    huff_sort_partition(v, 0, v->size());
}
```

Edit: I thought I'd add this since no one has answered this yet. If the code "should" work, then comment that (that way I can look for a reason outside this code for why it wont work).

Comment: Why can't you just use the qsort function that comes with c++?

Comment: @anio The main reason is that I'm doing it for learning, not for it to work. The other reason is it's a vector of pointers (so I can't use sort() either).

Comment: why are you doing b - e + 1 instead of e-b+1

Comment: @Yakov I didn't notice my error, since I just wrote the code and tried to run it and ran into this problem (which still persists even with that correction).

Comment: You could pass a function to `qsort` that deferences the pointers before comparing the objects.

Comment: C++ also provides a more generic `std::sort` function that works on vectors.  Similarly, you use a function that deferences the pointers before comparing; thus comparing the data pointed to, not the pointers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Though that would work, and if I don't find a solution to this problem I may do that, I would still like to know what's wrong with my program, since the main purpose of this project was for learning.

Comment: @EmAdpres is that multiplying by -1. If so, why? If not, what is the "'*'-1'*'" (I'm not that great at c++, so I might just have never seen that syntax before).

Comment: @MikeG it means a mistake by one. Your code is trying to access an element past the end of an array. Similar mistake is in the first line, since you pass the number of elements there should be `e - b` instead of `e - b + 1`. One more thing, think about finishing recursion, your code lacks this.

Comment: @MikeG first time you call `huff_sort_partition(v, 0, v->size)` ! so `e-b+1` is vector->size+1 and `b+(rand() % (e - b + 1))` go out of index bound !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens in your code when there are several nodes with the pivot weight - for simplicity, consider the weights `[1, 9, 5, 2, 7, 5, 6, 8, 3, 7]` and perchance the pivot index is 5, so

```
void huff_sort_partition(vector<Node*>* v, int b, int e){
    int p = (*v)[b+(rand() % (e - b + 1))]->weight;
```

we have `p = 5`

```
    int l = 0;
    int r = e-b;
```

`l = 0` and `r = 9`

```
    cout << "P:" << p << "  L-R:" << l << "-" << r << endl;
    while(l < r){
        while((*v)[b+l]->weight < p){
            l++;
        }
```

`1 < 5`, then increment `l`, `l = 1`, `v[1] = 9 > 5`.

```
        while((*v)[b+r]->weight > p){ // where it freezes up and wont move on
            r--;
        }
```

`7 > 5`, decrement `r`, `r = 8`, `v[8] = 3 < 5`. Swap `v[1]` and `v[8]`, giving `[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7]`.

Next round, `l = 1 < 8 = r`. `v[1] = 3 < 5`, `l` becomes 2, `v[2] = 5` isn't smaller than 5, end of loop. Now the second inner loop is entered, `v[8] = 9 > 5`, `v[7] = 8 > 5`, `v[6] = 6 > 5`; `v[5] = 5` isn't larger than 5, swap `v[2]` and `v[5]`, giving `[1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7]`.

Next round, `l = 2 < 5 = r`, `v[2] = 5` isn't smaller than 5, `v[5] = 5` isn't larger than 5, swap `v[2]` and `v[5]`. Oops, we're stuck.

The usual way to prevent this is to swap the pivot out of the way and have one of the two conditions a weak inequality, also one must check the condition `l < r` also in the inner loops, or in the case all entries are equal one would run off the end of the array/vector. Then after partitioning, one swaps the pivot into the right place.

The following code uses the standard way (untested, typos possible):

```
void huff_sort_partition(vector<Node*>* v, int b, int e){
    // Nothing to sort if there are fewer than two elements
    if (e <= b) return;
    int tempt = b+((rand()%(e-b))+1);
    int p_idx = (*v)[tempt]->weight;
    // swap pivot out of the way
    Node *tmp_Node = (*v)[tempt];
    (*v)[tempt] = (*v)[e];
    (*v)[e] = tmp_Node;
    cout << tempt << endl;
    int l = b;
    int r = e - 1;
    cout << "P:" << p_idx << "  L-R:" << l << "-" << r << endl;
    while(l < r){
        while((l < r) && (*v)[l]->weight < p_idx){
            l++;
        }
        while((l < r) && (*v)[r]->weight >= p_idx){
            r--;
        }
        if (l < r){
            Node* s = (*v)[l];
            (*v)[l] = (*v)[r];
            (*v)[r] = s;
            // stuff at l and r is okay now, we don't need to test again
            ++l;
            --r;
        }
    }
    // Now l is the first index with weight >= pivot weight,
    // swap pivot into place
    tmp_Node = (*v)[l];
    (*v)[l] = (*v)[e];
    (*v)[e] = tmp_Node;

    huff_sort_partition(v, b, l-1);
    huff_sort_partition(v, l+1, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with `b,l` use and stop condition .
`b` is an index from where to start patition, `e` is an index where to stop .
So when you call a function for the first time for `e` you have to refer last index and not size .
Also you are missing stop condition in `huff_sort_partition` - in order not to run forever you should check if `b` and `e` indices are ok relatively to each 0ther.

please try the fixed version of your code below

```
void huff_sort_partition(vector<Node*>* v, int b, int e){ 
        if (b >= e ) {
            return;
        }
        int p = (*v)[b+(rand() % (e - b + 1))]->weight; 
        int l = 0; 
        int r = e-b; 
        cout << "P:" << p << "  L-R:" << l << "-" << r << endl; 
        while(l < r){ 
            while((*v)[b+l]->weight < p){ 
                l++; 
            } 
            while((*v)[b+r]->weight > p){ 
                r--; 
            } 
            Node* s = (*v)[b+l]; 
            (*v)[b+l] = (*v)[b+r]; 
            (*v)[b+r] = s; 
        } 

        huff_sort_partition(v, b, b+l-1); 
        huff_sort_partition(v, b+r+1, e); 
        cout << "P:" << p << "  L-R:" << l << "-" << r << endl; 
        for_each(v->begin(), v->end(), show_freq); 
    } 
    void Huff::huff_sort(vector<Node*>* v){ 
        srand ( time(NULL) ); 
        cout << "------sort------" << endl; 
        huff_sort_partition(v, 0, v->size() - 1); 
    }
```